# Numeration of dynamically created elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create elements (in this case selectors) via a button while also beeing able to delete them via another button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10;
    var wrapper         = $(".container1");
    var add_button      = $(".add_form_field");

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if(x < max_fields){
         x++;
        $(wrapper).append('<div> <fieldset class= "field1"> <select class= "selector1" name="selector*[add numeration here]*"> </select> </fieldset>  <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>   </div>'); //add selector box
      }
      else
      {
        alert('You Reached the limits')
      }
      });
      $(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--
        ;})
});
```

I have no idea, how I can dynamically numerate the selector names from 1 to 10 via the var x. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need a `name=selectX` anyway?  Is it to POST the form?  If so, it will depend on your back-end, eg asp.net-mvc will require it as `selector[N]` not `selectorN`.  Also note that you don't need the `var x` as you can do this dynamically within the click handler `if ($("select.selector1").length <= 10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like `name="selector' + x + '"`, but the question is what should happen with the count if i delete 1.?

Notes:

`if (x < max_fields) {` currently only allows you to make 9, so if you want to make 10 use `if (x <= max_fields) {`

I've also moved `x++` to the end of the if statement so it does not increase the number until the end.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10;
  var wrapper = $(".container1");
  var add_button = $(".add_form_field");

  var x = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var s = FindNext();
    if (s > 0) {
      $(wrapper).append('<div> <fieldset class= "field1"> <select class= "selector1" name="selector' + s + '"> </select> </fieldset>  <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>   </div>');
      x++;
    } else {
      alert('You Reached the limits')
    }
  });
  $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })

  function FindNext() {
    for (var i = 1; i < max_fields; i++) {
      if ($('select[name="selector' + i + '"]').length == 0) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add_form_field">add</button>

<div class="container1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought about that way but the issue is, that since you can delete objects, you can create 2 selector elements with the same name(e.g. you create 5 selectors, delete the second and the third one and then start creating new ones again) and this might cause issues for me.